# How to handle answer which answers and loops another question in it?

Tags: support

This answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48040172/7664524

> I fixed it, I just cleared the cache in my browser, and the blog.css
>   from the cache is not found anymore. Thanks for you help! =)
>
> Last and/or additional question, how do I avoid these types of
>   problems in the future?

The first statement gives an answer to the question but then it again asks another question in it. How to handle such an answer? With flag (not an answer or moderator intervention)? Or with just downvote?

Comment: I just leave comment. Like "You prevent that doing XYZ". Or "That question merits it's own post. Please post it  as a separate question on site XYZ". And then just upvote the answer if it's good/helpful

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As long as the answer contains an answer to the question, it’s a valid answer.

---

“Not an Answer” flag is reserved for answers that doesn’t ***at all*** answer the question (comments, questions... posted as answers). And “in need of moderator’s intervention” are for special case situations (ie. when you need to report the user).

I don’t believe a downvote is necessary, since the answerer (who’s also the OP) posted their solution on what fixed their problem. Furthermore, you should encourage OPs’ to continue to post self-answers, as they might end up helping similar not experienced users who encountered the same problem.

An answer shouldn’t contain another question, therefore the appropriate action to take is to edit the question out of the answer. And kindly provide a comment stating the reason why you removed the comment (possibly an answer to their question, if you feel like it), keeping in mind that the OP is still a newcomer to SO.

Comment: And while you're at it, edit out the "thanks" and smiley and other such clutter.

Comment: Followup question to your answer (yes, I know I'm so Meta): what does the bit about "(possibly an answer to their question, if you feel like it)" mean?

Comment: The OP asked a minor question "How do I avoid these types of problem in the future" in their self-answered solution. I'm saying that it doesn't hurt to also answer the simple question, it will greatly help the OP. Don't forget to remind the OP that asking follow up question isn't very acceptable, but it should be either included in the question body of the initial main question or another post.(Final Note: I would expect the follow-up question to be minor and on-topic. If the OP later asked a random, off-topic question out of the blue, I would recommend posting another question and not answer)

Comment: If the follow-up question regards a problem your solution caused. You should definitely try to help the OP, unless you think the problem is too great, and posting another question would be more beneficial to the OP.